# Gurobi Warning and Inconsistency in Optimal Value [some integer variables take values larger than the maximum supported value (2000000000)]

Tags: gurobi

I am using Gurobi version 8.1.0 and Python API version 3.6 to solve MIP problems. I have two models in which I believe that their global optima are equal. However, I found out that they are not equal in one of my simulations. I then tried to warm-start the model that I believe the solution is incorrect (model-1) with the solution from another model (model-2). In other words, the problem is to maximize the objective function and the objective value of model-1 is 42.3333, but I believe it should be 42.8333. Therefore, I use the solution from model-2 with the objective value of 42.8333 to warm-start to model-1.

What is weird is that the solution from model-2 should not be feasible to model-1 since the objective value is greater than 42.3333 and the problem is maximization. However, it turns out that it is a feasible warm start and now the optimal value of model-1 is 42.8333. How can the same model have multiple optima?

```py
Changed value of parameter timeLimit to 10800.0
   Prev: 1e+100  Min: 0.0  Max: 1e+100  Default: 1e+100
Changed value of parameter LogFile to output/inconsistent_Model-1.log
   Prev: gurobi.log  Default: 
Optimize a model with 11277 rows, 15150 columns and 165637 nonzeros
Model has 5050 general constraints
Variable types: 0 continuous, 15150 integer (5050 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e-02, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 5e+01]
Presolve removed 6167 rows and 7008 columns
Presolve time: 0.95s
Presolved: 5110 rows, 8142 columns, 37608 nonzeros
Presolved model has 3058 SOS constraint(s)
Variable types: 0 continuous, 8142 integer (4403 binary)
Warning: Markowitz tolerance tightened to 0.0625
Warning: Markowitz tolerance tightened to 0.125
Warning: Markowitz tolerance tightened to 0.25
Warning: Markowitz tolerance tightened to 0.5

Root relaxation: objective 4.333333e+01, 4856 iterations, 2.15 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0   43.33333    0  587          -   43.33333      -     -    3s
     0     0   43.26667    0  243          -   43.26667      -     -    4s
     0     0   43.20000    0 1282          -   43.20000      -     -    4s
     0     0   43.20000    0  567          -   43.20000      -     -    4s
     0     0   43.18333    0 1114          -   43.18333      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.16543    0 2419          -   43.16543      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.15556    0 1575          -   43.15556      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.15333    0 2271          -   43.15333      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.13333    0  727          -   43.13333      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.12778    0 1698          -   43.12778      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.12500    0 1146          -   43.12500      -     -    5s
     0     0   43.12500    0 1911          -   43.12500      -     -    6s
     0     0   43.11927    0 1859          -   43.11927      -     -    6s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2609          -   43.11845      -     -    7s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2631          -   43.11845      -     -    7s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2642          -   43.11845      -     -    7s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2462          -   43.11845      -     -    8s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2529          -   43.11845      -     -    8s
     0     0   43.11845    0 2529          -   43.11845      -     -    9s
     0     2   43.11845    0 2531          -   43.11845      -     -   14s
    41    35   43.09874   17  957          -   43.09874      -  29.4   15s
    94    84   42.93207   33  716          -   43.09874      -  22.1   31s
   117   101   42.91940   40 2568          -   43.09874      -   213   37s
   264   175 infeasible   92               -   43.09874      -   133   73s
   273   181 infeasible   97               -   43.09874      -   277   77s
   293   191   42.42424   17 1828          -   43.09874      -   280   90s
   369   249   42.40111   52 2633          -   43.09874      -   311  105s
   383   257   42.39608   59 3062          -   43.09874      -   329  152s
   408   265   42.39259   65 2819          -   43.09874      -   386  162s
   419   274   41.51399   66 2989          -   43.09874      -   401  170s
   454   282   41.29938   71 3000          -   43.09874      -   390  182s
   462   280 infeasible   74               -   43.09874      -   423  192s
   479   287 infeasible   78               -   43.09874      -   419  204s
   498   293   40.51287   81 2564          -   43.09874      -   435  207s
   526   307   40.16638   86 2619          -   43.09874      -   419  227s
   584   330   42.63100   33  621          -   43.09874      -   404  236s
   628   333 infeasible   37               -   43.09874      -   394  252s
   661   345   42.37500   26   25          -   43.09874      -   396  288s
   684   353 infeasible   30               -   43.09874      -   426  290s
   842   370 infeasible   69               -   43.09874      -   348  306s
   944   379 infeasible   86               -   43.09874      -   321  370s
  1009   395   42.36667   22   25          -   43.09874      -   350  409s
* 1031   243               3      42.3333333   43.09874  1.81%   343  409s
  1056   203   43.00000   19  141   42.33333   43.09874  1.81%   362  411s
  1194   222     cutoff   23        42.33333   43.00000  1.57%   325  430s
  1199   219     cutoff   25        42.33333   43.00000  1.57%   349  450s
  1202   212     cutoff   29        42.33333   43.00000  1.57%   361  472s
  1211   200 infeasible   47        42.33333   42.91851  1.38%   380  498s
  1226   169 infeasible   43        42.33333   42.91471  1.37%   395  511s

Cutting planes:
  Gomory: 2
  Cover: 15
  Implied bound: 1
  Clique: 26
  MIR: 17
  Inf proof: 1
  Zero half: 8

Explored 1426 nodes (502432 simplex iterations) in 512.68 seconds
Thread count was 4 (of 4 available processors)

Solution count 1: 42.3333 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Warning: some integer variables take values larger than the maximum
         supported value (2000000000)
Best objective 4.233333333333e+01, best bound 4.233333333333e+01, gap 0.0000%
```

In addition to the above, I also received this warning: 
"Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Warning: some integer variables take values larger than the maximum
         supported value (2000000000)". What does it mean? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are encountering some numerical troubles. The root relaxation required an increased Markowitz tolerance, which indicates an ill-conditioned matrix. This may lead to inconsistencies as you have observed in the two different "optimal" solutions.

The warning about too large values means that there are integer variables with solution values so large that the integer feasibility tolerance can not reliably be checked anymore. If you have a variable with solution value in the range of 1e+9 it probably doesn't matter anymore whether they are integer or not. So you could probably also simplify your model by making them continuous variables.

You should check for violations in the two solutions for both models (see [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/quality_attributes.html)) to see how feasible the solutions actually are.